# Count how much data particular user is using in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have found similar question [How to Get True Size of MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714750/how-to-get-true-size-of-mysql-database) except question looks at working out a full size of DB..

I am was wondering how can we workout the size of entries that belong to a particular user.

I have users table and a table for their records that they store, also there is another table that stored documents in blob.. so I would want to select all tables with user ID = x and than workout the size of data.. is this possible?

At the moment I am thinking give each entry approximate size i.e. 1MB and if they have 100 entries than user have used 100MB of data.

Comment: Databases, tables, columns and rows are not owned by a user in a mysl database management system.

Answer (score 0):

There's a OCTET_LENGTH function that tells you the size of the blob, like so:

SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(content) FROM Posts WHERE userId = 1;