# Understanding DB level caching in RAM for POSTGRESS and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, caching

Imagine we have a MYSQL DB that's data size is 500 MB.

If I will set the innodb_buffer_pool_size at 500MB (or more), is it correct to think that all the data will be cached in RAM, and my queries won't touch disk?

Is effective_cache_size in POSTGRESS is the same as MYSQL's buffer_pool and it also can help avoid reading from disc?

Answer (score 0):

Is "effective_cache_size", a parameter to indicate the planner as to what OS is actually doing ?

http://www.cybertec.at/2013/11/effective_cache_size-better-set-it-right/

and for caching the tables, do we not need to configure "shared_buffers" ?

And with regards to MySQL, yes the "innodb_buffer_pool" size will cache the data for Innodb tables and preventing disc reads. Make sure its configured adequate to hold all the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track in regards to MySQL innoDB tables. But you must remember that when measuring the size of a database, there are two components: data length and index length.

[MySQL database size.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169120)

You also have no control over which databases are loaded into memory. If you want to guarantee a particular DB is loaded, then you must make sure the buffer pool is large enough to hold *all* of them, with some room to spare just in case.

MySQL status variables can then be used to see how the buffer pool is functioning.

I also highly recommend you use the buffer pool load/save variables so that the buffer pool is saved on shutdown and reloaded on startup of the MySQL server. [Those variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-preload-buffer-pool.html) are available from version 5.6 and up, I believe.

Also, check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341) out in regards to sizing your buffer pool.