# Why does InnoDB give obviously false free space information

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I tried to know how much extent ( "free space" ) does my database have after deleting a rather large table. ( Around 10GB )

I have run the command:

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", 
round( sum( data_free ) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ) "Free Space in GB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

which gave me a list of databases, and their "free spaces".

The problem is, that the database which had the 10GB table removed now has a 1500GB+ free space according to this report which is **significally bigger than my actual hard drive capacity**. ( which is around 200GB )

How is this possible? How could I get a more realistic report? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

As an experiment, I have added and removed an 1GB table in this database, now the report shows around 110GB more free space. Might there be a problem with my configuration, or is this a common issue?

Comment: Is there an overflow (in the SUM)? If not, which table(s) are reported as abnormally large?

Comment: I cannot really track back the table itself, since it has been dropped. I only see this abnormality in the parent database's size. How could I identify a potentional overflow you have mentioned?

Comment: But... Are you sure you can just SUM the free space? Isn't it share between them all?

Comment: Yeah, I am not familiar with the subject this deep. I found the query I used here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714750/how-to-get-true-size-of-mysql-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is answering some of the questions buried in Comments.)

**Misnomer**  "Free" space only includes whole blocks, not spare room inside blocks, and many other details.

Case 1:  **All tables are in `ibdata1`** -- `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or the equivalent query into `information_schema` will show the same `Data_free` value, namely how much is free in `ibdata1`.  This space can be reused by any table.  It is hard to give the space back to the OS.

Case 2:  **All tables are `file_per_table`** -- Now each `Data_free` refers to the space for the table.  And the `SUM()` is meaningful.  (ibdata1 still exists, but it does not contain any real tables; there is a lot of other stuff that InnoDB needs.)

Case 3:  **Mixture** -- If you turn file_per_table on/off at various times, some tables will be in ibdata1, some will have their own tablespaces.

Case 4:  **CREATE TABLESPACE in 5.7** -- For example, you can have a tablespace for each database.

Case 5:  **PARTITIONed tables** -- Each partition acts like a table.

Case 6:  **8.0** -- Even more changes are coming.

**Database == Directory**  In MySQL's directory tree each database can be seen as a filesystem directory.  Within that directory can be seen some set of files for each table.  The `.frm` file contains the table definition.  If an `.ibd` file exists, the table was created with file_per_table.  This may be the most reliable way to discover whether the table is file_per_table.  (8.0 will have significant changes here.)

**How much space can I reuse**?  There is no good answer.  Usually inserting a row will find space in the block where it belongs, and Data_free will not shrink.  But, if there were block split(s), Data_free can drop by some multiple of 16KB (the block size) or 4MB (the "extent size" - or maybe it is 8MB?).  Also, random inserts lead to BTree blocks being, on average, about 69% full.

**Changing `innodb_file_per_table`** has no effect until the next `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`.  And then it only has effect on where to put the newly created/copied data+indexes (ibdata1 or .ibd).  It will not destroy data.

**Big tables** usually have 4MB to 7MB of Data_free.  When computing how many rows you can add, don't plan on Data_free dropping below that range.

**Avg_row_size** should be useful.  But sometimes it (and Rows) are poorly approximated.  Their product (Data_length) is always correct.  So, this *might* be a good estimate of "rows to go before grabbing more space from OS:

```
(Data_free - 7M) / Avg_row_size
```

**Tablespace Recommendations**:  Put 'big' tables in file_per_table.  Put 'tiny' tables in ibdata1 or database-specific tablespaces (5.7).  Sorry, no simple recommendation on the dividing line between 'big' and 'tiny'.  And it is clumsy to migrate a table:  `SET global innodb_file_per_table = ...;`; logout; login (to pick up the global); `ALTER TABLE tbl ENGINE=InnoDB;`.  And it is necessarily a full copy of the table.

(**Caveat**:  I have left out many details.)

Comment: Thanks, Rick! What do You think about this alternative solution. Assuming that I have **Case 1** if I measure the actual file size of the `ibdata1` file with `ls -l` and I substract the data size measured from mysql `data_length + index_length` can I get the "real" free space approximately?

Comment: Maybe it would be interesting.

Comment: I did it, and it seems approximately realistic.

Comment: I don't know how many of miscellaneous data structures there in ibdata1.  But if the formula works for you, fine.

Comment: A caution:  An `ALTER TABLE` or a multi-row `UPDATE` or ... may temporarily grab a bunch of space in ibdata1, possibly growing the size of the file before your formula shrinks back to about where it had been.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you do not have **innondb_file_per_table** set, and are therefore using a shared table space. If so,  then you will be reurning the global 'allocated but unused' shared space, repeatedly for each table_schema.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds logical, thanks. How could I make sure this is my issue? Is there a way to find out if I have **innondb_file_per_table** set within the mysql environment?

Comment: You can confirm the current state via...

show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';
innodb_file_per_table | ON
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

Though this may not reflect the actual usage of tables that existed prior to making a setting change.

Comment: If you have filesystem command line access, then each table will have its own .ibd file (in /var/db/mysql or similar), if the setting is ON.

Comment: I am sure it wasn't changed in a long time. It had to be declared at the installation of the mysql module on the server. The query you have attached says that **innodb_file_per_table** is set to `OFF`

Comment: You will probably have an ibdata1 (or more) file in /var/db , this will be the communal shgared table space including any unused alllocated space left over after deletions. I don't think that you can have pre-existing tables with their own .ibd files if the setting is OFF, be very careful if you change the setting, it might delete exiting data etc.

Comment: I see, thank You. Could You please provide some ideas in your answer on my other sub-question about how could I reliably get the free size of this database? Like _How could I reliably know how much space can I (re)use before InnoDB starts reserving more space on my hard drive?_