# How to find out tables size in a database

Tags: mysql

I have a large Mysql database. Its size is more than what I expected.

How can I find size of its tables ? I need to find that table makes the database size huge.

Thank you.

Comment: what you mean size here

Comment: Do you use phpmyadmin? It should have this info available in the tables' list.

Comment: Or this query from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as below.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", 
      sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema
```

#### [Read Here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-find-DB-size-and-table-info-in-MYSQL-1040.php)

Answer (score -1):

use this query

```
show table status from <db_name>;
```

if your database name is users; then use this :

```
show table status from users;
```

[Check This - Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)