# MySQL dump of large database appears to be less than original MySQL database itself

Tags: database, backup, mysql

I am backing up a database whose size is about 190 GB. I want to back up the database to a local file. This is the command I am using:

```
mysqldump -u root -p tradeData > /db_backup/tradeData.sql
```

I have enough space on my machine. I tried a bunch of times and got no errors, but I am always getting a result file whose size is around 122GB.

Does anyone have experience with backing up large databases? My machine is a Linux one.

Comment: I use [this material](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database) for checking the database's size.

Comment: Got it. I am importing the backup file into the database and then I will compare their sizes.

Comment: Thanks very much. It is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using information like [the SQL query here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database) won’t give you a one-to-one connection between your local DB dump and what is actually in the system. Actual DBs have indexes and data that only exist when the DB is actually a DB in the database.  As [`RolandoMySQLDBA`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18227/20395) explains:

> From the dump file size, it is hard to judge because the combined
>   total size of data pages and index pages maybe far less that the size
>   of ibdata1 the dump was created from.

So my guess is your database includes InnoDB tables among other things that bloat the DB when compared to a bare dump.