# Google Cloud SQL Storage Usage High Issue

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have Setup Cloud SQL in google cloud with configuration of Tier db-n1-standard-4 with storage of 100GB SSD. My actual database size is having only 160MB Max but in Cloud Cloud SQL instances it showing up to 72GB used i don't know why? and its still increasing per day about 10GB. Can anyone explain about this issue.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you only see 160MB when using query from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database

Comment: Yes its coming of size 352 MB with sql query.

Comment: @Rupeshkumar finally the problem was what was said by Vadim?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time this is due to binary logs that are used for replication. 
The growth of binary logs is roughly proportional to the amount of modified rows.

Binary logs are purged after 7 days so the space will stabilize after 7 days.

Comment: Hey Vadim, I'm having the same issues and I was wondering if there is a way to confirm that its the binary logs with the sql command at all? Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue. After executing `SHOW BINARY LOGS;` in phpmyadmin, the MySQL said "#1381 - You are not using binary logging". So I guess for my case it's not due to binary logs? Any other possible reason or how can I check the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are enabling `general_log` option. Check `EDIT -> Cloud SQL flags -> general_log`. If this is `on`, turn it to `off`.