# CloudSQL Storage Usage Issue

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a database in GCP's CloudSQL with these configurations.
[image]

Storage usage has increased exponentially in recent weeks. In just about 1 month, the storage usage increased from about 2 TB to 3 TB. It's just an anomaly in our case since, way before, our storage usage did not increase that drastically (e.g., just MBs instead of GBs).

I've also queried the total storage usage in the database using this command.

```
SELECT table_schema AS "Database", 
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (MB)" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

And this was the output:
[image]

I have tried researching online about this issue, and it seems that it's not just me who has experienced it.

I looked at these StackOverflow issues already:

1. [Google Cloud SQL Storage Usage High Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486632/google-cloud-sql-storage-usage-high-issue/)
2. [Google Cloud SQL increasing size until full disk with no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094296/google-cloud-sql-increasing-size-until-full-disk-with-no-reason?rq=1)

So I thought that it's because maybe I have enabled the point-in-time recovery setting which uses binary logging. So,I already disabled that setting for the past two weeks (as seen in the first image). However, the storage allocation still hasn't gone down, and is still increasing at the moment.

Is there another reason why it hasn't been reduced yet?

**Edit:**
Some solutions say that I just need to make a SQL dump, make another instance, and import this dump. However, I am dealing with a production database with hundreds of users, and the estimated downtime would be around 2–3 days from exporting to importing the dump. I would not want to go with this workaround unless there's really no other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to ‘Temp data’ , such as data used by queries using temporary tables or sorting. They get accumulated due to inefficient queries being run on the instance.

You can try using commands like `\dt` to view temporary tables that might be using the space. You can identify the queries responsible for this by running this command
`show processlist;`

[Restarting the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#reclaimingspacetemp) will delete the ‘Temp data’. But, it will not reduce the disk size. To reduce the size you have to [Contact google support](https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/sql/docs/getting-support)

If the above solution does not work, Try the troubleshooting steps from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/troubleshooting#:%7E:text=Automatic%20storage%20is%20enabled.)

Comment: I tried restarting the instance and nothing happened. Same storage allocation reflected in the dashboard.

Comment: I also tried running the command `\dt` through gcloud shell but there was no output.

Comment: As I mentioned restarting instance only deletes the temp data, to reduce the disk size you have to contact google support.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your statement. I thought that "not reduce the disk size" means the actual set storage. Does this mean that the one reflected on my dashboard (the usage indicator) is a "false" output since the temp data is already deleted?

Comment: @JohnCymmer  Yes, As temp data will be deleted after restarting an instance,  you are getting output as false.

Comment: @JohnCymmer are you still facing the issue?

Comment: yes unfortunately. I was not able to try Google Support since it's not included in the basic package of Google's customer support. However, I've noticed that the storage doesn't move much and only slightly decreases over time.

Comment: Since it requires changes to be done by google engineers you should contact google support. consider buying [support package](https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/support#section-3) to get help from engineering team.

Comment: I was planning to but I was confused on what to buy. I'm confused whether the technical support from the engineering team is included in the "Standard Support" or not since the "Cloud Support API" is not included in the said package. If not, then it would be the "Enhanced Support" and it's very expensive. We can't afford it.

Comment: As per my knowledge, `standard support` provides [multi-channel technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support#:~:text=channel%20billing%20support-,Multi%2Dchannel%20technical%20support,-8/5%20response) which enough for disk reduction. You can also create and manage support cases using the [Cloud Support API](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/standard#support_cases). And, If my suggestions helped consider upvoting or accepting the answer, So that community  will know you are sufficiently helped.

Comment: I see. Let me verify first. Of course, I was not planning to ignore your answer. I will be accepting this one in case the standard support works.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Ive been getting the same issue and how i solved it was using the option of disabling point in recovery in my cloudsql
As far as in my case the cloudsql went to 2TB before we could notice and I've taken a backup and restored it in a new Cloudsql
commands i used to check if logging is causing the issue
`SHOW BINARY LOGS;`
once i got the logs we can delete them manually till the binaries we want as below
`PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.001298';`
or simply follow the below steps which would delete all the logs
edited the new instance and disabled the point in recovery option which made the issue solve
below article as reference [Google Cloud SQL increasing size until full disk with no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094296/google-cloud-sql-increasing-size-until-full-disk-with-no-reason?rq=1)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34884243)