# How can I know the database size of specific database in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, size

I have a database named 'phonebook'. It contains 10+ tables with a moderate amount of data. 
Now I want to know the database size of this 'phonebook' database using MySQL query. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get size of mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this, it provides the size of a specified database in MBs.

Make sure you specify `DB_NAME`

```
    SELECT table_schema,
    ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
    FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema='DB_NAME'
    GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Hope this will help you ! .

Comment: thank you @taha for quick response, it is my desired answer.

Comment: To get size of all databases, do: ```SELECT
    table_schema AS 'DB Name',
    ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) AS 'DB Size in MB'
FROM
    information_schema.tables
GROUP BY
    table_schema;```

Answer (score 1):

**The following query can show the size of all the database individually in a table view:**

SELECT table_schema 'DB_NAME', 
        ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;

**The following query can show only the size of a specific database:**

SELECT table_schema, 
    ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
    FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema='DB_NAME' 
    GROUP BY table_schema ;

**The following query can show total tables, the total table row, DB size of a specific database:**

SELECT 
TABLE_SCHEMA AS DB_Name, 
count(TABLE_SCHEMA) AS Total_Tables, 
SUM(TABLE_ROWS) AS Total_Tables_Row, 
ROUND(sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024) AS "DB Size (MB)", 
ROUND(sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024) AS "Free Space (MB)" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' 
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA ;