# DataGrip: How to get database and table size for MySQL database?

Tags: datagrip

Using PhyMyAdmin for over a decade I am not looking into datagrip. On thing that I could not find is statistics on database and table size. How much size, how many rows (overwerview), index size in bytes and so on.

Where can I find data statistics in datagrip?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there is no such feature yet.

For those who came here from Google, you can try use SQL query:
MySql:

```sql
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / (1024 * 1024) "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;

SELECT table_name, round(((data_length + index_length) / (1024*1024)),2) as "size in megs" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "named_db";
```

PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('dbname') );
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('tablename') );
```

Sources:
https://jonathanstreet.com/blog/disk-space-database-table-mysql-postgresql/
[How to get size of mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733507/how-to-get-size-of-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

For the table, it is impossible now, please follow and upvote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4281

For the database, there is no even a feature request in DataGrip's tracker. Please add a new one.

Comment: Stunning! Such a professional tool, lacking such basic features.

Comment: AFAICT nothing has improved by 2023.

Comment: Jan 2, 2024: Happy New Year! In Windows 11, `CTRL+Q`  (or apparently just hovering over it) on a table gives me table information now. Using:
`DataGrip 2023.3.2 (Build #DB-233.13135.68, built on December 14, 2023)`